# Re use binding from one project to another (Pybind11)

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am working in a binding from C++ to Python by using Pybind11.

Imagine that there are two C++ projects: Project A and Project B.

Project A has already been bound to python. I installed this binding with a `.whl` by using `pip`.

Project B is the C++ project I am creating myself and I want to bind to Python. I wrote a function whose return type is a complex type defined in Project A. I can get this in C++ by simply including its header like: `#include "ProjectA/complexType.h"`. However, it is very difficult to expose this class to Python with the classic approach since it has a lot of attributes and methods.

Furthermore I would not like to do it myself since it has been already done since Project A has already been bound previously.

Is there any way in which I can reuse the binding of project A to make my project recognize this return type in python?

P.S.: I leave here an example of Project B binding:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "ProjectA/complexType.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

complexType myfcn(const std::string &filename)
{
    // Fcn body
    return complexTypeObject; 
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(mymodule, m)
{
    // Module doc
    m.doc() = "Doc.";

    // I do not want this since python cannot recognize the attributes of complexType. Also, 
    // I do not want to bind this class again
    py::class_<ProjectA::complexType>(m, "complexType");

   // Fcn binding:
   m.def("myfcn", &myfcn, "My fcn description");
}
```

I want to bind a C++ function, whose return type is a data structure. One of the members of that structure is a complex type object that is defined in another binding.

That other binding has been installed through a .whl by using pip.